# Nanoc - compile output different to nanoc view

Tags: nanoc

If you create a new `nanoc` site, and then run `nanoc view`, it works well. The CSS, pathing, and assets are correctly handled. However, when I run a `nanoc compile,` it's not handled the same way. I get broken CSS, broken paths etc.

What is causing this - I assume it's the rules and

Answer (score 1):

Compile only generates files in `/output`. Opening one of the html files there is possible, but as the docs state, your browser will not be able to find the CSS files.

Either use `nanoc view` to load CSS files correctly, or use a local web server to view the files. (Note: `nanoc view` is nothing more than a local web server).

Comment: Is there anyway to compile directly to plain old HTML and CSS? I am trying to load my blog on github pages. It seems to use the raw output folder. Sorry for inane questions (haven't done much since I asked the question).